# How can we find minimum radius of circle which contains $\arctan^2(x)+\arctan^2(y)=a$?

Tags: maxima-minima, implicit-function

How can we find  minimum radius of circle which contains $\arctan^2(x)+\arctan^2(y)=a$, where I think $a<\pi/2$?

For example I have some plots from WolframAlpha and I see it depends on $a$.

But have no idea how to find maximum radius because this is not simple implicit function.

[image]

Comment: This might be amenable to using polar coordinates.

Comment: @hardmath I believe it becomes an atrocious mess. Lagrange multipliers might be better?

Comment: If we take derivative with respect to $x$ we and set $y'=0$ we will find that $x=0$. Isn't that correct proof?

Comment: @Federico  yes, but perhaps we can do it neatly with a change of variables.

Comment: @user8053696:  no, the maximum radius might come at $x=y$.  In that case the derivative would be $\pm 1$

Comment: Just looking at plots for various values of $a$ convinces me that the maximum radius comes along the axes, like on the plot you show.  Then you get $r=\tan \sqrt a$ easily.  I don't have a proof that this is true.

Comment: @RossMillikan that's precisely what i'm saying in my answer

Comment: That's a cute way of getting a quasisquare with rounded corners! I'll have a look at _parametrisations_ of that for arbitrarily choosing the sharpth of the corners ... I find that kind of thing extremely interesting, & sent in a post on it a while back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the smallest circle is always tangent at $x=0$ or $y=0$. So you can put $\arctan(x)^2=a$ and solve $x=\tan\sqrt a$. This would be the radius.

**Edit:** let's make it rigorous.

Let's maximize $x^2+y^2$ with the constraint $\arctan(x)^2+\arctan(y)^2=a$. By symmetry we can work in the positive quadrant. With Lagrange multipliers we find
$$
\left(\frac{\arctan(x)}{1+x^2},\frac{\arctan(y)}{1+y^2}\right)
= \lambda (x,y),
$$
therefore (unless $x=0$ or $y=0$, which are easily seen to be stationary points) we have
$$
\frac{\arctan(x)}{(1+x^2)x} = \frac{\arctan(y)}{(1+y^2)y}.
$$
We want to show that the only possibility is $x=y$. The we need an argument to say that this is a minimum and not a maximum.

As a matter of fact, the function $\frac{\arctan(x)}{(1+x^2)x}$ is decreasing, so this shows that $x=y$ are the only solutions. Its derivative is in fact
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\arctan(x)}{(1+x^2)x} &=
\frac{2}{x
   \left(x^2+1\right)^2}-\frac{2 \arctan(x)}{x^2
   \left(x^2+1\right)}-\frac{4 \arctan(x)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2} \\
&< \frac{2}{x
   \left(x^2+1\right)^2}-\frac{2 \arctan(x)}{x^2
   \left(x^2+1\right)} \\
&= -2 \frac{(1+x^2)\arctan(x)-x}{(x+x^3)^2} < 0.
\end{split}
$$

You may rightfully wonder why is $(1+x^2)\arctan(x)-x>0$? Well, it vanishes at $0$ and its derivative is $2x\arctan(x)>0$.

So, why is $x=y$ a minimum? Well, we just need to compare it with the point at $y=0$.

The values of $x^2+y^2$ at the two points are respectively $2(\tan\sqrt{a/2})^2$ and $(\tan\sqrt a)^2$. Since the function $f(t)=(\tan\sqrt t)^2$ is convex and vanishes at $0$, it is superadditive, implying that $2f(a/2)\leq f(a)$.

---

**Bonus**

I'd like to add one little piece, related to proving that $(1+x^2)\arctan(x)-x$ is increasing. The insight is that it is of the form $\frac{g(x)}{g'(x)}-x$ with $g$ concave. Then it's derivative is $-\frac{g(x)g''(x)}{g'(x)^2} \geq 0$. I don't know if this general detail might be useful to someone.

Comment: Can we prove that smallest circle is always tangent at $x=0$ or $y=0$?

Comment: @user8053696 not at the moment

Comment: Could you, please, clarify why we are sure that $x=y$ is a minimum?

Comment: @user8053696 I added the proof of this last bit

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! Many thanks.

Comment: @user8053696 It is also quite lucky that it works without too many troubles :D

Comment: I've also added one little bonus at the end

Comment: All in all, I find this an awesome exercise for students. I'll try to remember it

Comment: I have the similar more interesting problem. Maybe you can help, please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3034053/how-can-we-find-some-radius-of-circle-which-fully-contains-x-arctanx-axy-arc

Comment: @Tag it seems that someone has already answered that. thanks for the invitation anyway :)

Comment: Unfortunately that answer is not complete at all as can be seen from the graph I've plotted https://i.imgur.com/WNs8Tw9.png and can't be accepted.